# Static redirection in .htaccess with rewriterule

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I should make some url redirections (no variables to pass) in .htaccess but I don't want to let see the destination url. How can I make?
I've already tried to use Redirection instruction like this:

```
Redirect /en/folder1/url1 /en/folder2/url2
```

But in this way the destination url is visible. So I started to try to use RewriteRule like in this example:

```
RewriteRule ^/en/folder1/url1$ /en/folder2/url2
```

but I've always error page as result.

P.S. This code is inside a .htaccess file with the default Wordpress url rewrite code.

EDIT. This is the complete .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^en/folder1/url1$ en/folder2/url2

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the leading slash from your Rule's pattern

```
RewriteEngine on 



 RewriteRule ^en/folder1/url1$ /en/folder2/url2 [L]
```

Comment: What url are you going to and what error does the server return?

Comment: The url is en/folder1/url1 but wordpress load the custom error page and doesn't show the correct page. I've edited the original question to include the entire code of .htaccess

Comment: Ok, looks like your wordpress rules are conflicting with this. Put this at the top before your other rules

Comment: Does /folder2/url2 work if you type it in browser address bar?

Comment: I've put my rule after RewriteEngine On and before Wordpress rewrite rules but doesn't work. If I type en//folder2/url2 the correct page is loaded

Comment: I think this is because of the relative target path, The rule's target is relative to the server root , try changing **en/folder2/url2** to **/en/folder2/url2** so that it can find the file in correct location

Comment: To avoid this kind of problem i've tried to insert the absolut path in this way `RewriteRule ^domain.xx/en/folder1/url1$ domain.xx/en/folder2/url2 [L]` but with no success – chattago2002 10 mins ago

Comment: Can somebody tell me because this code make a "redirect" and not a rewrite? `RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]+)?/url1$ /?lang=$1&p=4961 [NC,L]`